# cublas failed to synchronize stop event?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cublas

I'm playing with the [matrixMulCUBLAS](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/C/Projects/x64/matrixMulCUBLAS.zip) sample code and tried changing the default matrix sizes to something slightly more fun rows=5k x cols=2.5k and then the example fails with the error `Failed to synchronize on the stop event (error code unknown error)!` at line #377 when all the computation is done and it is apparently cleaning up cublas. What does this mean? and how can be fixed?

I've got cuda 5.0 installed with an `EVGA FTW nVidia GeForce GTX 670` with 2GB memory. The driver version is 314.22 latest one as of today.

Comment: Using this example, you can change the size of the matrices using the command line switch (`-sizemult=xx`) but you are limited to a sizemult of 10 or less which gives a max matrix size of (640,1280).  Since you are talking about much larger sizes, I assume you made some changes to the code.  Can you post those exact changes?  The matrix sizes are created by combining 3 different numbers, so I'm not sure what you changed to achieve those sizes.

Comment: Under windows you may also be hitting a TDR event, I'm uncertain about that.  The overall execution time for the cublas sgemm operations is fairly long for matrices of those sizes -- around 6-7 seconds on one test I ran.  You can probably work around this by reducing the `nIter` loop to 1 or a small number.  You would know if you're hitting a windows TDR event because the screen would go black briefly.  I tried modifying the 2 and 4 multipliers in the matrix size computation to 16 and 32, and had no trouble (although the host side computation takes a long time.)

Comment: Indeeed, I am hitting a Windows TDR event and have no idea how to prevent/fix it ... any ideas?

Comment: If you google "windows tdr" the first several hits are all from microsoft and they are the best references I know for what to do if you want to change the timeout period.  As I mentioned you can also try reducing the `nIter` loop, which will reduce the number of sgemm calls.  It may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when using CUDA on windows, it's necessary to make sure the execution time of a single kernel is not longer than about 2 seconds.  If the execution time becomes longer, you may hit a windows TDR event.  This is a windows watchdog timer that will reset the GPU driver if it does not respond within a certain period of time.  Such a reset halts the execution of your kernel and generates bogus results, as well as usually a briefly "black" display and a brief message in the system tray.  If your kernel execution is triggering the windows watchdog timer, you have a few options:

1. If you have the possibility to use more than one GPU in your system (i.e. usually not talking about a laptop here) and one of your GPUs is a Quadro or Tesla device, the Quadro or Tesla device can usually be placed in TCC mode.  This will mean that GPU can no longer driver a physical display (if it was driving one) and that it is removed from the WDDM subsystem, so is no longer subject to the watchdog timer.  You can use the `nvidia-smi.exe` tool that ships with the NVIDIA GPU driver to modify the setting from WDDM to TCC for a given GPU.  Use your windows file search function to find `nvidia-smi.exe` and then use `nvidia-smi --help` to get command line help for how to switch from WDDM to TCC mode.
2. If the above method is not available to you (don't have 2 GPUs, don't have a Quadro or Tesla GPU...) then you may want to investigate changing the watchdog timer setting.  Unfortunately this requires modifying the system registry, and the process and specific keys vary by OS.  There are a number of resources on the web, such as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570088(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft, as well as other questions on Stack Overflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186638/modifying-registry-to-increase-gpu-timeout-windows-7), which may help with this.
3. A third option is simply to limit the execution time of your kernel(s).  Successive operations might be broken into multiple kernel calls.  The "gap" between kernel calls will allow the display driver to respond to the OS, and prevent the watchdog timeout.

The statement about TCC support is a general one.  Not all Quadro GPUs are supported.  The final determinant of support for TCC (or not) on a particular GPU is the `nvidia-smi` tool.  Nothing here should be construed as a guarantee of support for TCC on your particular GPU.