# Is there a way to turn off Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) in Windows 7/8?

Tags: windows, cuda, operating-system

There are so many headaches brought with Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM), the latest being the weird 2G memory allocation bug on GPU.

Is there a way to turn off WDDM all-together or I have to go with Linux/windows xp 64?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, *per se* and is off-topic for [SO].

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a way to turn off WDDM mode for a GeForce GPU. If you have a Quadro or Tesla GPU, you can set the GPU to use TCC mode (use the `nvidia-smi` tool, with `--help` to figure out the command options to switch from wddm to tcc mode) but you will need another GPU in the system to host the display. You may also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186638/modifying-registry-to-increase-gpu-timeout-windows-7).

The statement about TCC support is a general one.  Not all Quadro GPUs are supported.  The final determinant of support for TCC (or not) on a particular GPU is the `nvidia-smi` tool.  Nothing here should be construed as a guarantee of support for TCC on your particular GPU.

Answer (score 1):

TCC mode works only on suppoted devices (Tesla, Quadro) . 
In these devices you can choose between WDDM and TCC mode, Most of modern Tesla devices support only TCC mode, physically these devices don't have a graphic output.

Run from command line the nvidia smi executable, which usually reside in: 
          C:\program files\nvidia coporation\nvsmi

```
      nvidia-smi -dm 0 -i 0
```

dm 0 for WDDM, dm 1 for TCC.

i flag set the device number, in case you have multiply devices in the system

Comment: Hi @TripleS! as you mentioned, Tesla and Quadro are only supported hardware, I have rtx 3090, that is Ampere—NVIDIA's 2nd gen RTX architecture. It has NVLink port, but the `nvlink-smi -i 0 -fdm 1` command is not working