# How to debug: CUDA kernel fails when there are many threads?

Tags: cuda, breadth-first-search

I am using a Quadro K2000M card, CUDA capability 3.0, CUDA Driver 5.5, runtime 5.0, programming with Visual Studio 2010. My GPU algorithm runs many parallel breadth first searches (BFS) of a tree (constant). The threads are independed except reading from a constant array and the tree. In each thread there can be some malloc/free operations, following the BFS algorithm with queues (no recursion). There N threads; the number of tree leaf nodes is also N. I used 256 threads per block and (N+256-1)/256 blocks per grid.

Now the problem is the program works for less N=100000 threads but fails for more than that. It also works in CPU or in GPU thread by thread. When N is large (e.g. >100000), the kernel crashes and then `cudaMemcpy` from device to host also fails. I tried Nsight, but it is too slow.

Now I set `cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 268435456);` I also tried larger values, up to 1G; `cudaDeviceSetLimit` succeeded but the problem remains.

Does anyone know some common reason for the above problem? Or any hints for further debugging? I tried to put some printf's, but there are tons of output. Moreover, once a thread crashes, all remaining printf's are discarded. Thus it is hard to identify the problem.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your VS2010 project?  I am just getting started with CUDA and have an interest in network analysis.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"CUDA Driver 5.5, runtime 5.0" -- that seems odd.

You might be running into a [windows TDR event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186638/modifying-registry-to-increase-gpu-timeout-windows-7).  Based on your description, I would check that first.  If, as you increase the threads, the kernel begins to take more than about 2 seconds to execute, you may hit the windows timeout.

You should also add proper [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your code, for all kernel calls and CUDA API calls.  A windows TDR event will be more easily evident based on the error codes you receive.  Or the error codes may steer you in another direction.

Finally, I would run your code with `cuda-memcheck` in both the passing and failing cases, looking for out-of-bounds accesses in the kernel or other issues.

Comment: Thanks Robert. My kernel runs too long. It works after I disable the WDDM TDR.