# Cuda crashed driver

Tags: c++, cuda, crash, driver

I defined, that array size is 13107200.
I try to run kernel with 25600 blocks and 512 threads. In system info defined, that Max_Grid_Dim_X = 2147483647 and Max_Block_Dim_X = 1024.
Nvidia driver keep crashing while the program runs.
How to fix it?

```
 __global__ void aesEncrypt(node *data, int rounds)
 {
     int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
     addRoundKey(&data[index], 0);
     for(int i = 1; i <= rounds; i ++) {
         subBytes(&data[index]);
         shiftRows(&data[index]);
         if(i != rounds)
             mixColumns(&data[index]);
         addRoundKey(&data[index], i);
     }
 }

aesEncrypt<<<dim3(25600, 1, 1), dim3(512, 1, 1)>>>(gData, r);
```

Comment: What operating system, CUDA version and GPU are you using? When you say crashing, what do you mean, *exactly*?

Comment: I use Windows 8, Nvidia GeForce GT 740m (driver version 320.57), Cuda version 5.5.20. 
In tray i can see message, that driver was stopped and restarted. Array contains the same data in each element.

Comment: You are hitting the Windows WDDM driver watchdog timer limit. There are a lot of questions already about this on [SO], for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6913206/681865) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21971484/681865) to name but a few. I'm voting to close this as a duplicate

Comment: Did you try to run your program with less blocks and with an array smaller? if it works, it only means that you reached the limit of your GPU.

Comment: It was driver time limit. I changed settings, now it works great. Thanks all for support.