# CUDA run lead to display drive stop

Tags: cuda, gpu

I wrote a function. When I run it in the cpu I can get the right result. The part of cpu code is:

```
for(int x = startx; x < endx; x+=SampleStep)
    for(int y = starty; y < endy; y+=SampleMin)
    {
        int idoff = Width;
```

Then I port it to the GPU, like this:

```
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + startx;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + starty;
int idoff = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
```

when I run the code, the black screen happened and then recovered after a little while. At the same time, the system showed the message like: `Display drive stopped responding`.

and the cuda event time output cost time is 0ms, the result is wrong.

```
for (int k = CircleBegin; k < CircleEnd; k++)
    {
        bool Isright = (k-ww>=0) && (k+ww<Width);

        if (Isright)
        {
            float AverR = 0;

            for (int i = -ww; i <= ww; i++)
            {
                for (int j = -wh; j <= wh; j++)
                {
                    AverR += ImgR[(k+i)+(y+j)*idoff];
                }
            }
```

when I comment the AverR += ImgR[(k+i)+(y+j)*idoff]; The code can run without black screen. I want to know why. Is this related with my display device (my device is nvida gt 240) or is there some access violation happened？ how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running your code on your laptop or PC you are also using for current work? What happens if you run it on a cluster or a remote machine? This happened to me as well, I guess the GPU is essential for normal work of the computer and if it is occupied too long, the system starts to panic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA - nvidia driver crash while running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272513/cuda-nvidia-driver-crash-while-running)

Comment: Did you check that x and y are less than endx and endy, as in your CPU for loops?  Just because you parallelize the loops doesn't mean you can legally access memory out of bounds...

Comment: Yes, i checked that using if.

Comment: Did you try running cuda-memcheck to ensure you are not accessing memory out of bounds?  Are you performing correct error checking? If you are, you will see either a timeout error or an unspecified launch error.  If the former, then @talonmies is right. Otherwise it's likely detectable using cuda-memcheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen is turning black because you are hitting the windows TDR event.  For further description of this and possible solutions, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317505/cublas-failed-to-synchronize-stop-event/17811933#17811933).

Since you have nested for-loops, and you haven't told us the size of the data set, it's certainly possible that your code is taking too long to execute, if your for-loops are operating over a large enough range.

When you comment out that line of code, the compiler can completely optimize away the loops, and so that section of code would take essentially zero time to run. As a result, your kenel is no longer taking too long and so you don't hit the TDR event.

There's no reason based on any of the above to assume an access violation is occurring.  In fact, I would say it is unlikely because an access violation will often cause an unspecified launch failure, which will terminate a running kernel.

So you'll need to investigate some of the ideas I mentioned in the answer I linked above.

Comment: What you need to do is to create a new key named TdrDelay of type REG_DWORD under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers and set its value to what ever you desire (value in seconds). After that you need to restart your computer for the setting to take effect. Solved!